# "Unexpected value NaN" error when dragging D3 objects with mouse

Tags: d3.js

I'm having difficulty getting some circles to move when asked to by the mouse.  I'm adapting this [example by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708), using the code below ([see jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/aB8jr/)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var points = [
    [100,100],
    [200,300],
    [250,150],
    [300,200],
    [350,350],
    [450,300],
    [450,400]
];

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .call(drag);

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I get this errors when trying to drag points with the mouse:

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing cx attribute.
...},c:t(f),d:function(n,t){return jt(n.getDate(),t,2)},e:function(n,t){return jt(n...
 1)

Unexpected value NaN parsing cy attribute.
...},c:t(f),d:function(n,t){return jt(n.getDate(),t,2)},e:function(n,t){return jt(n...
```

Grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not dealing with a mouse event (which has `x` and `y` properties set), but a mouse event wrapped in a drag event. You can access the source event through `.sourceEvent`:

```
d3.select(this).attr("cx", d[0] = d3.event.sourceEvent.x)
               .attr("cy", d[1] = d3.event.sourceEvent.y);
```

I've also changed the assignment to `d` to be consistent with how it's done to start with. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6MtVs/).

Comment: Cheers Lars. At least 2/3's solved. Firefox doesn't process this the same as Chrome and Safari (IE untested) - no errors but the points end up at the screen origin. At least on my system. Try your jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah, try `clientX` and `clientY` instead. Unfortunately, this is inconsistent across browsers.

Comment: The `clientX`  seem do not reflect the window scrolling. You may want to use `layerX` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/7d6uo7jw/